# R - ddply to act on 2 columns in 3 column data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to use ddply to act on 2 columns in 3 column data.frame. I know I've done this before, but for the life of me I cannot get anything to work. Here's the example:

```
func = function(x, y) {
  if(x>y) {
    x-y
  } else {
    0
  }
}
df = data.frame(name=c('w','x','y','z'), a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(4,3,2,1))
```

Here is what I've tried, along with many other things:

```
ddply(df, summarize, func(a, b))
ddply(df, mutate, func(df$a, df$b))
ddply(df, func)
```

The most common error is:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Expected output:

```
  name a b result
1    w 1 4 0
2    x 2 3 0
3    y 3 2 1
4    z 4 1 3
```

Comment: Your func has only one argument and you are using two arguments in `ddply`. Why is that?

Comment: sorry, fixed that...I was playing around with a bunch of things. Same issue with the edited function though.

Comment: Do you need to do this "by groups"? If not, then there is no reason to use `ddply`. Also, is this your real function, or just a simplified example? Because if this is your real function we could do a lot of work on it...

Comment: I guess your x and y arguments have nothing to do with values in name column?

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you showed your expected output for your example input too.

Comment: may be something like this works: `ddply(df,.(name), summarize, kk=ifelse(a>b,a-b,0))`. OR `func = function(x, y) {
  ifelse(x>y,x-y,0)}`; `ddply(df,.(name), summarize, kk=func(a,b))`.

Comment: I added the expected output.

Comment: @Gregor - yes, this is a very simplified example. But would love to hear what you are thinking.

Comment: Have you considered "upgrading" to `dplyr`? `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(result=pmax(0, a-b))`. `pmax` does the same as your function and is supposed to be faster than `ifelse`.

Comment: Or using `data.table` `setDT(df)[, result:= pmax(0, a-b)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ddply(df,.(name), summarize, result=ifelse(a>b,a-b,0))
```

OR

```
func = function(x, y) { ifelse(x>y,x-y,0)}
 ddply(df,.(name), summarize, result=func(a,b))
```

Run the code in [Rfiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=ex6tER7J)

Answer (score 0):

The point of `ddply` is split-apply-combine, that is breaking apart a data frame by some grouping variable, doing something to each piece, and putting it back together. You don't have a grouping variable, so there's no point in using `plyr::ddply`. (You can, as @user227710' answer shows, but it's not really *doing* anything it's intended for, like getting in your car to drive across a single street.) For the example in your question, the code should just be

```
# vectorized function
myfunc = function(x, y) ifelse(x > y, x -y, 0)

df$result = with(df, myfunc(a, b))
# then drop unused columns, if you want
```

The newer `dplyr` package is can do all the split-apply-combine stuff of `plyr`, but is also intended to clean up code in general, breaking tasks into small pieces and allowing you to "chain" them together.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, result = myfunc(a, b)) %>%
  select(name, a, b, result)
```